# Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric, but value is shorter than specified precision

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column which is defined in the table as follows

```
td_long_shr_qty (numeric(18,6), null)
```

when i update the column I am getting an error

```
UPDATE
    fact
SET
    td_long_shr_qty = 1720187931245.8069
WHERE
    id = 29
```

arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

is there any issue with this number `1720187931245.8069` as it is less than precison 18 why do i get this error.please help.

Comment: Why do you show us the column definition of `td_long_shr` but your query is updating `td_long_shr_qty`?    Are you looking at the wrong column definition?

Comment: Sorry i have updated the column name

Comment: 1720187931245 is more than 12 digits. numeric(18,6) means 18 digits in total, where are 12 before the decimal point, and 6 after.

Comment: `numeric(18,6)` is "18 digits, with 6 of those appearing after the decimal point". You cannot fit the number you're showing us into such a type.

Comment: No it's not. Your defined precision is 18 with a scale of 6. The value you are trying to enter has a precision of 17 with a scale of 4. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The meaning of `NUMERIC(18, 6)` is 18 total places of precision, 6 of which are to the *right* of the decimal point (if present).  So, this means that the largest number which this type can hold is:

```
 999999999999.999999
1720187931245.8069
```

I have deliberately pasted your number from the query below, and lined up with, the largest possible value.  It should be plain for you to see that it exceeds the capacity of `NUMERIC(18, 6)`.

Comment: You might want to include the relevant quot from ducomentation: "s (scale)
The number of decimal digits that will be stored to the right of the decimal point. This number is subtracted from p to determine the maximum number of digits to the left of the decimal point." other then that, +1.

Comment: @ZoharPeled But then wouldn't that mean that the OP's number _would_ in fact fit into `NUMBER(18, 6)`, since only 4 significant figures on the RHS means that there would be 2 extra places on the LHS?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not the way I understand it. your explanation is correct - the maximum number of the digits left to the decimal separator is the total number of digits (precision) minus the maximum number of digits to the right of the decimal separator (scale). So if the data type is `numeric(18,6) it can store up to 12 digits left of the decimal separator, just like you've explained.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Where did you find that in the documentation??? because I don't see it here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017   The sentence in your comment is a lot clearer than what's in the documentation I found.

Comment: @TabAlleman, Zohar got that quote from [decimal and numeric (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: @EricBrandt thanks!   MSDN should put that sentence in flaming bold letters in a bright yellow box.